# Smart Contract function keep return Null value?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, dapp-development

Hey I am new with Solidity. And I just tried to link my front end view  with the smart contract. With the simplest possible approach.

My contract:-

[image]

My JS code:-

[image]

Console keep printing 'null' I don't know why? I am sure about contract initialization because I used web-pack box.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you link artifactsToContract with web3

Comment: Yes, and I am sure about it. Because other functions work.  https://truffleframework.com/boxes/webpack   I had used this box as my boilerplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
await Test().call().then((data) => console.log(data));
```